# Retrofit and Okhttp doesn't work well on my Application

Tags: android

I used retrofit and Okhttp in my application and several errors are been thrown out, first i resolved by excluding okio and gson in the retrofit and okhttp i compiled but it is not working fine, it keeps bringing errors everytime which is Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class and another time it will bring out that of Okio as Okio/asyncTimeout, How can i solve this please?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mobilesec.jar')
    compile files('libs/org-apache-commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-commons-lang.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-1.51.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'){
        exclude module: 'com.squareup.okio'
    }
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Do you really need the okhttp dependency. As far as I know Retrofit builds on top of okhttp.

Comment: Well people typically use Gradle to fulfill their dependencies instead of random jars

Answer (score 0):

You have Gson and Okio jars duplicated.. remove

```
compile files('libs/gson-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.2.0.jar')
```

but.. why are you loading dependencies both via local jar and remote repositories? I suggest to use only remote dependencies.

EDIT: You can render the dependency tree with the command `gradle dependencies`. Run that and check why gson is added twice.

Comment: Can u please explain to me the disadvantage of loading over local jar over remote repositories

Comment: i am trying your answer now

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Comment: THAT is what i am getting now